# Speech Recognition on Windows Phone - speech-to-text

Tags: c#, windows-phone, speech-recognition

Hi, is there a way to use a PromptBuilder to develop a Windows Phone speech recognition app? I would like to make an app that can recognize my voice and do something with it in code, but I have to do it on Windows Phone. Can anyone help expand on that? If I can't use a PromptBuilder, is there a alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Speech.Synthesis` namespace only deals with speech synthesis, i.e. speech generation, not speech recognition, as per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Speech.Synthesis%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The N:System.Speech.Synthesis namespace contains classes for initializing and configuring a speech synthesis engine, for creating prompts, for generating speech, for responding to events, and for modifying voice characteristics.

There's also `System.Speech.Recognition` namespace, that deals with speech recognition, but I'm not sure about it's availability on Windows Phone.

For working with speech on Windows Phone you should start here: [Speech for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206958%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). They have their own `Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition` namespace for this purpose.